# How to go fullscreen with an onclick event - Phaser3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework, html5-fullscreen

Hi would like to know if we can go "real" fullscreen with a click event on a Phaser3 game. I tried so many things and nothing work.
I have an object and i would like to click on it to put the game on a fullscreen mode.
Hope someone had this problem before and can help me.

Config of game:

> ```
> const config = {
>     parent: "game",
>     width: 750,
>     height: 500,
>     type: Phaser.AUTO,
>     zoom: 1,
>     scene: [Loading, Menu, InGame, GameOver, Controls, Win],
>     backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
>     audio: {
>         disableWebAudio: true,
>         noAudio: false
>     },
>     physics: {
>         default: "arcade",
>         arcade: {
>             gravity: { y: 1500, x: 0 },
>             debug: false
>         },
>     }, }
> ```

```
window.onload = function() {
    var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
}
```

Object click event on scenes:

> ```
> this.fullScreenButton = this.add.image(730, 20, "fullScreen");
> this.fullScreenButton.setInteractive();
> this.fullScreenButton.on('pointerdown', function() {
>     this.scene.scale.setGameSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
>     this.scale.startFullscreen(); });
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
let fullscreen = this.add.image(16,16,'fullscreen').setInteractive();

fullscreen.on('pointerup',() => { 
  window['game']['canvas'][game.device.fullscreen.request]();
})
```

Comment: Do your use last version of Phaser 3 and look at https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/fullscreen/ and in what browser it was tested

Comment: i use the 3.19 version of phaser on Chrome. i got this error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: i try to make this.canvasElem = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas")[0];
        this.fullScreenButton = this.add.image(730, 20, "fullScreen");
        this.fullScreenButton.setInteractive();
        this.fullScreenButton.on('pointerup',()=>{
            this.canvasElem.requestFullscreen();
        }); it goes in fullscreen but for like 0.5sec

Comment: Look at working example : https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src/scalemanager/full%20screen%20game.js form labs https://labs.phaser.io/

Comment: This put the game on full screen but i would like the canvas fit the screen but only when it's on fullscreen. Look at what i mean on my screenshots. https://ibb.co/qr57YYZ https://ibb.co/fHFGw0K

Comment: you might need to define a [scaling configuration](https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/scalemanager) so your game scales to available space

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and don't know why but pointerdown has some problems with full screen mode. If you just switch to pointerup the canvas will fit the whole screen.

Hope this can be helpful.
Ab